# Using child-process in promises return error in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying execute a command with node.js "child-process" in a promise.
My problem is that using promises I get an error. I also tried using callbacks and the error is similar.

I have the next code:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const dgate =
  path.join(__dirname, "/api/dicomapi/dgate.exe") +
  " -p5678 -hCONQUESTSRV1 -q127.0.0.1";

function os_func() {
  this.execCommand = function (cmd) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }
        resolve(stdout);
      });
    });
  };
}

var os = new os_func();

os.execCommand(`${dgate} "--get_param:MAGDevice0"`)
  .then((returnvalue) => {
    console.log(returnvalue);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

I get an error:

```
Error: Command failed: F:\Programas\vuejs\nuxt-iclindoctor\server_iclindoctor\api\dicomapi\dgate.exe -p5678 -hCONQUESTSRV1 -q127.0.0.1 "--get_param:MAGDevice0"

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:672:12) {
  killed: false,
  code: 4294967295,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'F:\\Programas\\vuejs\\nuxt-iclindoctor\\server_iclindoctor\\api\\dicomapi\\dgate.exe -p5678 -hCONQUESTSRV1 -q127.0.0.1 "--get_param:MAGDevice0"'
}
```

If I use without promises, it works well:

```
exec(`${dgate} "--get_param:MAGDevice0" `, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  console.log("pac", stdout);
});
```

results:

```
pac f:\programas\appprog\dicomserver150c\data\
```

Comment: are you sure there is no error? it can write to stdout and report an error at same time.

Comment: Yes, I am  sure there is no error

Comment: I mean the part of "If I use without promises" doesn't check for `error`, the 2 code are not equal.

Comment: "*I also tried using callbacks and the error is similar.*" and "*If I use without promises, it works well*" - wait, which is it now?